# De-broglie wavelength in electron microscope

Tags: wave-particle-duality

The de Broglie wavelength is given by

$$\lambda\equiv\frac{h}{mv}$$

Now, if we have a *small* body, it's wavelength will be large when it is in motion. Similarly, a *large* body will have small wavelength. It can be seen from the equation. First of all tell me if I am right about these observations.

I was studying electron microscope and there was a sentence in it,

> The fact that microscopic particles as the electron have extremely short de Broglie wavelengths has been put to practical use in many ultra modern devices.

It says that the electron, being a small particle, has a short de Broglie wavelength. But if we look at the equation, we see that *small* bodies will have large wavelength (provided that my observations about the equation are correct).

So my question is: why does a *small* particle as the electron has a small wavelength?

Comment: it is related to mass not the size of the particle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement:

> "the fact that microscopic particles like electron have extremely short de-broglie wavelengths has been put to practical use in many ultra modern devices."

is talking of the [wavelength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie_wavelength), which does not only depend on rest mass( your m is the relativistic mass) :

[image: wavelength dBroglie]

The electron gets to relativistic velocity  much faster than heavier particles, and that makes the difference to the wavelength, the gamma.

Comment: this link is useful for defining when relativistic effects should be taken into account http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/rellim.html